# Creating an object fro csv data

Tags: python

I want to create an object(maybe list?? still waiting for suggestions) that contains data read from a .csv file
The data looks like this:

> [‘;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Number;;Semester;;Grade;;;’]

> [';;;;;;;;;;;;;;1;;I;;A;;;']

> [‘;;;;;;;;;;;;;;2;;I;;C;;;']

> [';;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;II;;A;;;']

I'm thinking this could be solved using regex.
The idea is that the first row determines the order in which 'number, semester, grade' appears and the next rows are what we need to store.

Answer (score 0):

How about using pandas and the read_csv?

```
import pandas
pandas.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',',header=1)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).